# PHP Server Side Events works, but takes 10-15 seconds to fire the first time

Tags: php

I'm using SSE for a webapp. It should fetch a DB each second. This is the PHP Code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    include 'includes/connection.php';

    while(1){
        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `turns` ORDER BY due ASC');
        $turns = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM state');
        $state = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo 'data: {' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'data: "status": "ok",' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'data: "content": '.json_encode($turns) . ',' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'data: "state": '.json_encode($state) . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'data: }' . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;

        ob_flush();
        flush();

        usleep( 800 * 1000 );
    }
?>
```

The first event it receives takes like 10-15 seconds on the server (instantly on my local machine) but after that it fetches the DB each 800ms as expected with no delay whatsoever.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: My guess is that you either don't have indexes setup correctly, or your mysql database does not have enough memory to keep all of its indexes in memory and has to load them from disk on first query. After that it keeps them in memory. Try diagnosing this issue by looking at the data from iotop,htop and nload to see what's bottlenecking.

Comment: @Dimi but it's weird, because `turns` has 20 rows maximum, and `state` only has one row... Besides, before using SSE I was using an ajax call with an interval and the first query worked instantly even on the server.

Comment: Try adding this at the start `ob_implicit_flush();ob_end_flush();` and see if anything changes... If your issue is not on DB side, and resources are not an issue then the way you transfer data is next logical thing to check

Comment: inside the while loop or outside?

Comment: right after headers.

Comment: Added but still happens

Comment: @Dimi if it helps, I opened the URL in the browser and it took the browser 15-20 seconds to open the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200683/discussion-between-dimi-and-nick).